# Utilizing Imported Functions in Angular for Interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the below component where I am attempting to utilize a function that I've created called `FormatDate` that displays the date in a particular way. I was expecting to implement it via interpolation in my html however the function is not recognized. Is there a way to utilize it without wrapping it in a function local to the component? I read through the [Angular - Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) documents but nothing jumped out to me.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormatDate } from '../shared/commonFunctions';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<h3>{{FormatDate(rightNow)}}</h3',
})
export class myComponent {
    rightNow = Date();
}
```

My workaround is below, but it is unsightly to me so I was hoping to find a way around it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormatDate } from '../shared/commonFunctions';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<h3>{{dateFormat(rightNow)}}</h3',
})
export class myComponent {
    rightNow = Date();

    dateFormat(date: string): string {
        return FormatDate(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think angular `pipe` is a thing You are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({name: 'transformDatePipe'})
export class TransformDatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(date: string, params:any...): any {
        return yourFunction();
    }
}
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormatDate } from '../shared/commonFunctions';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    template: '<h3>{{rightNow|transformDatePipe:anyAdditionalParamsYouNeed}}</h3',
})
export class myComponent {
    rightNow = Date();
}
```

Don`t forget to add your new Pipe to the module declarations array.
https://angular.io/guide/pipes